# C++ delete operator. How to use properly?

Tags: c++

Please help a novice with operator **`delete`**
Demo code:

```
MyType getDataFromDB()
{
    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;
    Statement *stmt;
    ResultSet *res;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "login", "pass");
    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("schema");
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    MyType resultAnythngAndAnother;

    // First query
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT anything");

    while (res->next())
    {
        // fetch data from "SELECT anything"
    }

    delete res; // <----- Question #1: Should I every time call delete res before next assigning of res variable?

    // Another query
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT another");

    while (res->next())
    {
        // fetch data from "SELECT another"
    }

    delete res; // <----- Question #2: Is it enough to call delete res only once here? Since it won't be used anymore.

    return resultAnythngAndAnother;
}
```

- Question #1: Should I every time call delete res before next assigning of res variable?
- Question #2: Is it enough to call delete res only once? Since it won't be used anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: Since res is assigned with new address, if you don't call `delete` in `#1`, you will lose access to allocated memory. So yes, you have to call `delete`  everytime you assign new memory to the pointer.

Comment: @BlackMoses Where in the code says that res is assigned with a new address? Why can not`stmt->executeQuery("SELECT anything");` just return a pointer to a memory owned by stmt?

Comment: Why in heavens (replace by arbitrary spiritual fantasy) name are you returning pointers everywhere. You should be using objects that understand how to do the management of their own resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first

```
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT anything");

while (res->next())
{
    // fetch data from "SELECT anything"
}

delete res; // <----- Question #1: Should I every time call delete res before next assigning of res variable?
```

the answer depends on what the documentation says about the functions affecting `res`.  In this case, the answer comes down to the behaviour of `stmt->executeQuery()` and `res->next()`.   While I would anticipate the call of `res->next()` would not affect whether you need to release `res` or not, reading the documentation is the only way to be sure.

If the documentation explicitly says you are required to `delete res` when done, then you should do so.

If it says you are required to call some other functions (say `Release(res)`) when done, you should do so.

If the documentation says nothing at all about this, you are best off doing nothing.   When you don't know, `delete res` when `res` is not a pointer that should be `delete`d is more likely to give unwanted effects than doing nothing.

For the second, if (and only if) you are required to `delete res`, only ever do it once.   Deleting a pointer twice gives undefined behaviour.

In short:  only `delete res` if you know it is required, and don't `delete res` more than once.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `std::make_unique` - avoid naked pointers entirely unless you have a special case where you're not going to be responsible for freeing the object.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes.
2. For every new, there must be one delete, otherwise you will have memory leak. You just delete once after you're done using whatever you've allocated.

Another good programming practice is to do

```
res = nullptr;
```

So you wont have any dangling pointers. But that's not needed in this specific piece of code

You should also read about smart pointers, new and delete should not be used in modern c++ according to bjarne stroustrup.

Comment: `res` is local to the function, so there isn't much scope for dangling pointers.

Comment: `res = nullptr;` doesn't affect other copies of the pointer. It doesn't eliminate dangling pointers. If your design allows for the possibility of dangling pointers you need to fix the design, not apply band aids.

Comment: How are you sure that res own the memory returned by `stm->executeQuery("SELECT anything");`

Comment: *"For every new, there must be one delete"* More precisely, there must be *exactly* one `delete`  for every `new`. Double deletes are UB.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you allocated with `new` or the documentation for the function that you're calling says the client must release the memory using `delete`, then you should **not** blindly call `delete` on that pointer.

You do not know where that pointer comes from.  It could have been created with `new`, it could have been created with `malloc`, it could be a pointer within a larger pool of memory, you don't know.

What is usually the case is that the documentation will state to call some other function to release the memory or handle.